# How to show a specific code only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Example site: http://www.oneupme.com/

If you visit the site from IE you will see a red box that says you are using a old browser!!
What is interesting is that there is no IE if conditions. Maybe hi use javascript to check if it is IE and then with jquery add the code.But in js files there no such code. Any ideas how hi accomplish it.

// Update: Or maybe he use php to detect the browser and then set and variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either do it in the client side [using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2599002/29407) or on the server side using the `User-Agent` HTTP header.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is to use IE conditional comments. That site might have used [CSS hacks](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/).